# Zope properties disappearing

Tags: properties, zope

I wrote a new user-class based on BasicUser and PropertyManager. Now I can add and change properties. But when I restart the server, they are gone.

Any ideas where I could find the cause of this behaviour?

Threre are a number of properties defined in the class (_properties). These are not affected.

Comment: You should really add the code, this will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: There is nothing special about the code used: I added the property using manage_addProperty and changed it with manage_changeProperties. This works fine as long as I do not restart.

Comment: Even more reason to show the code, including the class.

Comment: Also: "Threre are a number of properties defined in the class (_properties). These are not affected." - But... these are the properties. So I'm not sure what you mean here.

Comment: Only the properties added (with manage_addProperty) after the creation of the objct are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing base class was "Persistent". I assumed that it must be a base class of PropertyManager but it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Data that disappears when you restart the server is almost always something that is an effect of the changes not getting written to the Database properly.

This in turn usually happens because you are modifying a list or a dictionary and not persisting the object to disc. There are various ways of getting around this problem. In the case of properties, you should use the object methods for updating and adding properties.

These are called `manage_addProperty`, `manage_editProperties`, `manage_delProperties` and `manage_changeProperties`.

You can find examples of usage at the bottom of [this page](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/BasicScripting.html) in the Zope2 Book.

Comment: I use manage_addProperty and manage_changeProperties. It works fine as long as the server runs.

Comment: Silly me. I had to add Persistent to the base classes. BasicUser does not have it, but User (from AccesControl) does. Thanks Lennart, you pointed me in the right direction with your answer.